# Jenkins Docker container behind traefik reverse proxy with path-matching rule

Tags: docker, jenkins, traefik

I have a Docker container running a [traefik reverse proxy](https://traefik.io) like so:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  --name traefik-reverse-proxy \
  --network="host" \
  -p 80:80 \
  -v /dev/null:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  traefik:1.5-alpine \
    --docker
```

Then I run another container with Jenkins which configures forwarding-rules via labels so that `traefik` will forward all requests to it whose path starts with `/jenkins`:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  --name jenkins \
  --label "traefik.port=8080" \
  --label "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix: /jenkins" \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Now, opening `http://localhost/jenkins`, the request is correctly forwarded to the Jenkins container which redirects me to the main `index.html` page. However, the page is mostly blank because the JavaScript and CSS assets are not loaded correctly.

Looking into the browser console, I can see that the index page is trying to load them from addresses like `http://localhost/static/4e9c623d/scripts/yui/button/button-min.js` which do not exist in this setup. Rather, it should include the `/jenkins/` part in the URL and try to load them from e.g. `http://localhost/jenkins/static/4e9c623d/scripts/yui/button/button-min.js` instead - manually hitting that URL shows me the JS file in the browser.

I tried to use a rule combination like `--label "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix: /jenkins; AddPrefix: /jenkins/"` but this did not change anything.

How would I have to write the rules to make this work properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the custom path to an environment variable e.g. `-e JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"` when running the Jenkins container.

See https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#configuring-reverse-proxy